# Sql server 2005 find series in number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in following format

```
89279
89280
89281
89282
89283
89284
89285
89286
89287
89288
160447
160448
160449
160450
160451
160452
160453
160454
160455
160456
160457
160458
```

i want the o/p in the following format  in sql server 2005

```
89279   89288   10
160447  160458  12
```

Comment: I believe the requirements could be more clear...

Comment: Please don't edit the question to ask something different. I'll have a quick look at that though.

Comment: [SQL Fiddle for that one](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b794d/1). Ask a new question for any other changes.

Answer (score 9):

A standard "gaps and islands" query.  [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a219/2)

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                YourColumn - DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY YourColumn) AS Grp
         FROM   YourTable)
SELECT MIN(YourColumn),
       MAX(YourColumn),
       COUNT(YourColumn)
FROM   T
GROUP  BY Grp
```