# series in number with sum SQLserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

With reference to my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17419034/1551233) question,  Can I include one more column:

```
89279   50
89280   50
89281   50
89282   50
89283   50
89284   50
89285   50
89286   50
89287   50
89288   50
160447  50
160448  50
160449  50
160450  50
160451  50
160452  50
160453  50
160454  50
160455  50
160456  50
160457  50
160458  50
```

and have o/p like

```
89279   89288   10 500
160447  160458  12 600
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think anyone understands what you're asking.

Comment: i dont know about anyone else but i really dont get what your trying to do here...maybe a little more info or some examples of what you have tried so far??

Comment: This is a comment/additional info of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419034/sql-server-2005-find-series-in-number

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
WITH T
AS
(
  SELECT *,
   col1 - DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS Grp
  FROM   Table1
)
SELECT 
    MIN(col1)
   ,MAX(col1)
   ,COUNT(col1)
   ,SUM(col2)
FROM   T
GROUP  BY Grp
```

Edited Martin post : [Sql server 2005 find series in number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419034/sql-server-2005-find-series-in-number)

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4aaf6/3)